# The planes $\lambda x+y+z=\lambda-1,x+\lambda y+z=\lambda-1,x+y+\lambda z=\lambda-1$ form a triangular prism.

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

The planes $\lambda x+y+z=\lambda-1,x+\lambda y+z=\lambda-1,x+y+\lambda z=\lambda-1$ form a triangular prism.Then find the value of $\lambda $.And find the distance of the origin from an edge of the prism.

---

Is there a method or formula by which $\lambda $ can be found out.Please help me.

Comment: Determinant formed by Coefficients of plane is $=0$ and $\lambda\neq 1$

Comment: Why $\lambda\neq 1$ determine the prism?I did not understand the logic behind this.@juantheron

Comment: bcz when $\lambda=1\;,$ Then all equation of  plane are same that is $x+y+z=0$

Comment: Ok and why did the determinant formed by coefficients of plane is $=0?$@juantheron

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eHpJJT5TNGwC&pg=PA920&lpg=PA920&dq=condition+for+forming+triangular+prism+by+using+plane&source=bl&ots=rpJZNhmXjW&sig=V9_Dprx3-8KEnbLcGCMwo1KirEk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAmoVChMI0Jrlle2vyAIVicSOCh3nwwH0#v=onepage&q=condition%20for%20forming%20triangular%20prism%20by%20using%20plane&f=false